# shared_ptr<> is not required to use reference count?

Tags: shared-ptr, c++11, reference-counting

Do I understand the new Std right that `shared_ptr` is not **required** to use a *reference count*? Only that it is likely that it is implemented this way?

I could imagine an implementation that uses a hidden linked-list somehow. In N3291 "20.7.2.2.5.(8) shared_ptr observers [util.smartptr.shared.obs]" The note says

> [ Note: use_count() is not necessarily efficient. — end note ]

which gave me that idea.

Comment: The C++ standard specifies very little in terms of required implementation (nothing I can think off), but prefers to define things in terms of required behavior. That way the implementers are free to provide the best implementations possible (for the target space of their compiler). In my mind this is very symmetrical as in application development you always try and hide implementation details behind public interfaces that provided the required functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, nothing in the spec *requires* the use of an explicit "counter", and other possibilities exist.

For example, a linked-list implementation was [suggested for the implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/smarttests.htm) of boost's `shared_ptr`; however, the proposal was ultimately rejected because it introduced costs in other areas (size, copy operations, and thread safety).

Answer (score 5):

## Abstract description

Some people say that `shared_ptr` is a "reference counter smart pointer". I don't think it is the right way to look at it.

Actually **`shared_ptr` is all about (non-exclusive) ownership**: all the  `shared_ptr` that are copies of a `shared_ptr` initialised with a pointer `p` are **owners**.

**`shared_ptr` keeps track of the set of owners**, to guaranty that:

- while the set of owners is non-empty, `delete p` is not called
- when the set of owners becomes empty, `delete p` (or a copy of `D` the destruction functor) is called immediately;

Of course, to determine when the set of owners becomes empty, `shared_ptr` only needs a counter. The abstract description is just slightly easier to think about.

## Possible implementations techniques

To keep track of the number of owners, a counter is not only the most obvious approach, it's also relatively obvious how to make thread-safe using atomic compare-and-modify.

To keep track all the owners, a linked list of owner is not only the obvious solution, but also an easy way to avoid the need to allocate any memory for each set of owners. The problem is that it isn't easy to make such approach *efficiently* thread safe (anything can be made thread safe with a global lock, which is against the very idea of parallelism).

### In the case of multi-thread implementation

On the one hand, we have a small, fix-size (unless the custom destruction function is used) memory allocation, that's very easy to optimise, and simple integer atomic operations.

On the other hand, there is costly and complicated linked-list handling; and if a per owners set mutex is needed (as I think it is), the cost of memory allocation is back, at which point we can just replace the mutex with the counter!

## About multiple possible implementations

How many times I have read that many implementations are possible for a "standard" class?

Who has never heard this fantasy that the complex class that could be implemented as polar coordinates? This is idiotic, as we all know. complex **must** use Cartesian coordinates. In case polar coordinates are preferred, another class must be created. There is no way a polar complex class is going to be used as a drop-in replacement for the usual complex class.

Same for a (non-standard) string class: there is no reason for a string class to be internally NUL terminated and not store the length as an integer, just for the fun and inefficiency of repeatedly calling `strlen`.

We now know that designing `std::string` to tolerate COW was a bad idea that is the reason for the unusual invalidation semantics of const iterators.

`std::vector` is now guaranteed to be continuous.

### The end of the fantasy

At some point, the fantasy where standard classes have many **significantly different reasonable implementations** has to be dropped. Standard classes are primitive building blocks; not only they should be very efficient, **they should have predictable efficiency.**

A programmer should be able to make portable assumptions about the relative speed of basic operations. A complex class is useless for serious number crunching if even the simplest addition turns into a bunch a transcendental computations. If a string class is not guaranteed to have very fast copy via data sharing, the programmer will have to minimize string copies.

An implementer is free to choose a different implementation techniques **only when it doesn't make a common cheap operation extremely costly** (by comparison).

For many classes, this means that there is exactly one viable implementation strategy, with sometimes a few degrees of liberty (like the size of a block in a `std::deque`).

Comment: I don't think "shared_ptr keeps track of the set of owners" is correct. It would be ok to say that informally, but you wrote that in bold. The bullet items are true, though: need to delete when the last owner goes. I don't think it is "required" or "obvious" to implement `shared_ptr` as a linked list. Thanks four your insights into the history of different implementations, I am quite sure there *is* much freedom for implementors left, esp. for `shared_ptr`. Microsoft uses two counters (shared, eak), afaik.

Comment: @towi "_I don't think "shared_ptr keeps track of the set of owners" is correct._" Can you **prove** that it is incorrect? "_It would be ok to say that informally, but you wrote that in bold._" I meant it as a formal, **abstract description** (as the title says).

Comment: @towi "_Microsoft uses two counters (shared, eak), afaik._" Using two ref counters is mandatory for the implementation `boost::shared_ptr`: one ref counter before calling the saved destruction functor, one ref counter for freeing the ref counters. The second ref counter is for `weak_ptr`: a `shared_ptr` is a strong reference to the managed object, to the destruction functor, to the strong ref count and to the (strong+weak) ref count; a `weak_ptr` is a weak reference to the managed object and a  **strong** reference to both ref counts.

Comment: @towi You can imagine that `weak_ptr` is implemented in term of a `__shared_ptr` to the ref counts structure, where `__shared_ptr` is just like `shared_ptr` except that `__shared_ptr` does not have weak ref support: a `weak_ptr` is a `__shared_ptr` to the data structure that keeps track of the last `shared_ptr` to the managed object.

Comment: @cuiousguy: Your comments are correct, of course. To your question: No, I can not prove "`shared_ptr` may not keep track of its owners". I have only experience with `shared_ptr` as a user (not knowing the specs by heart, only the interface) and my own implementation of *a* shared pointer (which may or may not be akin to `shared_ptr`).

Comment: @towi "_not knowing the specs by heart, only the interface_" A specification does not need to be unique: you can have many different specifications that describe the same "reality". Just like you can have different axioms for arithmetic or set theory. You can choose the axioms you prefer, and you can choose the specification of `shared_ptr` that you prefer.